# Make one sbt config depend on another

Tags: scala, sbt

The sbt documentation shows example of how to declare dependency only between projects. But I'm positive that there are ways to declare one config be dependent on another, just like the Test configuration uses classpath from the Compile configuration.

How can I declare my own configuration so that it would depend on the Compile config generated classpath?

---

I take a more close look to suggested solution and bunch of question arose again. So I reopen the question

I can not deduce sbt behavior solely from the delegate relation between Test and Compile config.

The source directories turn out to be completely different for Test and Compile config despite being delegated.

```
> show test:unmanagedSourceDirectories
[info] List(./src/test/scala, ./src/test/java)
> show test:scalaSource
[info] ./src/test/scala
> show test:javaSource
[info] ./src/test/java
> show compile:unmanagedSourceDirectories
[info] List(./src/main/scala, ./src/main/java)
> show compile:scalaSource
[info] ./src/main/scala
> show compile:javaSource
[info] ./src/main/java
```

And other significant keys such as `unmanagementClasspath` and `fullClasspath` are not `SettingsKey`s that may be naturally stacked with delegating. They are full-fledged `TaskKey`s that stores complex procedure for generating class-paths behind them.

So, the question is still actual: How can I mimic exporting classes from Compile to Test config for my custom defined config? And there is closely related optional question: how this is actually done for aforementioned pre-defined configs?

Comment: I think your assumption is wrong. Delegation is not inheritance. When the key is delegated it means that if it's not defined in a given scope its value will be resolved from delegated scopes. Doesn't matter really if it's a task key or a setting key. Try `inspect` command to see delegation chain. The key `unmanagedSourceDirectories` is simply defined in a scope `Test`, hence it's not delegated (you even quoted documentation in one of your comments). Maybe you can show what you have and we will be able to help you to get it to the state where you want to be.

Comment: `unmanagedSourceDirectories` is not delegated and it is exactly what I want to point to. So other mechanics different from delegation is used to providef Test sources with dependecnies from Compile sources. And I search how it was done by sbt or how I can reproduce it in other way

Comment: Output of `inspect test:unmanagedSourceDirectories` is `Delegates:
test:unmanagedSourceDirectories, runtime:unmanagedSourceDirectories, compile:unmanagedSourceDirectories` so clearly there is a delegation.

Comment: This delegation is not used because `test:unmanagedSourceDirectories` is rewritten from scratch. And it may be checked with `show` as I illustrated in the question body

Comment: Clearly, that's how the delegation works. Maybe what you want is just getting the value, like in `(unmanagedSourceDirectories in Test).value`, and then let's say work on that value.

Answer (score 3):

You can make one configuration extend another. You do that by using `extend` method.

```
lazy val MyConfig = config("myConfig") extend(Compile)

lazy val root = project.in(file(".")).
    configs(MyConfig).
    settings(inConfig(MyConfig)(Defaults.compileSettings ++ Defaults.compileInputsSettings): _*)
```

Extend will delegate to `Compile` in this case, for settings which are undefined in the `MyConfig` configuration.

You can check it by running SBT and executing for example `show myConfig:managedClasspath`, the output should be exactly the same as for `show compile:managedClasspath`.

If you inspect your new configuration's `managedClasspath` you'll see that it delegates to the `compile`.

```
[info] Delegates:
[info]  myConfig:managedClasspath
[info]  compile:managedClasspath
[info]  *:managedClasspath
[info]  {.}/myConfig:managedClasspath
[info]  {.}/compile:managedClasspath
[info]  {.}/*:managedClasspath
[info]  */myConfig:managedClasspath
[info]  */compile:managedClasspath
[info]  */*:managedClasspath
```

As I've stated above, SBT will only delegate to the setting if it's not defined in the given configuration.

For example, if you do not define any specific compiler options for `myConfig` the settings will be taken from `compile`.

```
> show compile:scalacOptions
[info] List()
> show myConfig:scalacOptions
[info] List()
```

Changing setting in `compile` configuration will have an effect on `myConfig`:

```
> set scalacOptions in Compile += "-Xexperimental"
> show compile:scalacOptions
[info] List(-Xexperimental)
> show myConfig:scalacOptions
[info] List(-Xexperimental)
```

Overriding the setting in `myConfig` will make SBT to use the setting defined in that configuration, while `Compile` will have its own value:

```
> set scalacOptions in MyConfig  := Seq("-Xcheck-null")
> show compile:scalacOptions
[info] List(-Xexperimental)
> show myConfig:scalacOptions
[info] List(-Xcheck-null)
```

Note the delegation is one way. Change to the `MyConfig` has no influence on the `Compile` configuration.

You can check the [documentation](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Testing#custom-test-configuration) for details.

Comment: And what if I have no need to extend Test configuration since I have no test to be performed?

Comment: I think I don't get it. It was just an example, you can extend any configuration you want. In your example that would be `Compile`. I added that point to my answer.

Comment: And what exactly would be done when I extend configuration? Doest it automatically add other configuration to dependencies? Documentation you provided give no information about it. It presents example for very concrete case and no information about more general ones

Comment: Maybe there is a misunderstanding. This will make all settings of `Compile` to be defined in your new configuration (where you could override specific settings). Maybe you can tell what you want to achieve, and I'll be able to edit / update the answer. Do you need a value of a setting from another configuration or do you want to create new configuration being copy of another one?

Comment: I'd like to add results from Compile:compile as managed classpath to MyConfig:compile. It should work like http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Multi-Project.html#dependencies. And it seems that Test and Compile configuration relates exactly in way that I'm looking for

Comment: I check documentation http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Scopes.html#delegation . It says "A scoped key may be undefined, if it has no value associated with it in its scope.

For each scope, sbt has a fallback search path made up of other scopes." So delegation works for non-defined settings but not for redefined, such as Test:unmanagedSources

Comment: Check my updated answer on your last comment. This is basically the behaviour. You could override unmanagedSources, as well, I've chosen compiler option because it's easier to make up an example.

Comment: I've evaluated some examples, as you suggested, and discover that your assumptions are right, and the sbt delegate documentation are wrong about working only for non-defined settings, it also works for settings defined with +=

Comment: reopened question since delegation seems to be insufficient to reproduce desired behavior