# Adding Custom Configuration's Classpath to Test Configuration in Sbt

Tags: sbt

I created a configuration that will build my project with some **extra** classes than the normal Compile configuration. I managed to create the configuration, it works and even "knows" the classes from the normal Compile.

The code:

```scala
lazy val DomainUtil = config("domainUtil") extend(Compile)
lazy val domain = (project in file("cmwell-domain")).configs(DomainUtil)
  .settings(
    inConfig(DomainUtil)(Defaults.configSettings)
  )
```

Package also works and I get the normal jar and the "...-domainUtil.jar"

But now I want the Test configuration to know the new classes compiled in the custom configuration. How can I do it?

Thanks,
Eli

P.S. I think that it's the same question as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23586436/make-one-sbt-config-depend-on-another/23586561) (years ago) but it wasn't answered there.

Comment: In the `domain` project definition, you can say `.configs(DomainUtil, Test extend DomainUtil)`. Is that what you want?

Comment: Thanks! Your trick does cause the domainUtil configuration to be compiled when running `Test / compile`. But:

1. The domainUtil jar isn't created, only the Compile one
2. The test classes cannot recognize the domainUtil classes (which is quite obvious, the jar isn't there)
3. Somehow, Scalatest classes are not recognized in the test classes
Any idea?